# facebooksdk.jar missing from Android Dependencies library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to create my first Android app using Facebook SDK.  I've been following tutorials at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrJsLFAYITI.  Originally everything was working fine at set up/downloading Facebook SDK and it was not giving me any errors when I was writing the application.  Then I tried to run the application on the emulator and I didn't see anything on it. Then, when I tried to fix this, I started to get several errors not seen in the tutorial.

The current errors I'm getting are "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application" and "R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!"  I've seen the second error before and gotten it to go away by deleting R.java and having it be rebuilt and then cleaning my projects, but that doesn't work now.

Looking in my libraries folder for the project it looks like the problem is that my Android Dependencies library is missing the facebooksdk.jar from its bin folder.  I've tried redownloading from the Facebook developers site and github (and even tried to do this on another computer) but it always seems to be missing.  I downloaded another facebook-sdk.jar and added it as an external jar to my project but that doesn't seem to help.  (Also, it will not allow me to manually modify the Android Dependencies library, so I can't do anything there.)

I saw several posts with similar questions related to a missing facebooksdk.jar and tried out all their solutions but nothing has worked for me.

I've tried: cleaning/rebuilding, reconfiguring build path, changing compiler compliance, etc.

Does anyone have suggestions?  Thank you so much!!!

(Also, I've noticed my FBAndroid-7.0.0.apk is also missing from bin (and my whole computer).)

Comment: are you using the official version of facebook? downloaded from fb website

Answer (score 1):

If the error you are seeing is like 'The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/facebook/bin/facebooksdk.jar' (You can see it in Problems window of Eclipse)

Then close all other projects and just build 'FacebookSDK' project. If this gets build successfully, it will generate facebooksdk.jar at the required path.

Now, open your project. Clean and build.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The steps [here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/fixed-android-dependencies-missing.html) works for me.If the jar is not getting generated, set the Java compiler version to 1.7. Close all projects and clean only FacebookSdk

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.